# Python dictionaries - find second character in a 2-character string which yields minimum value

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to submit the first part of a key and return the remaining part of that key which minimizes the value (and starts with the first part).

For example:

```
d = {'ab': 100,
     'ac': 200,
     'ad': 500}
```

If I were to pass in `'a', I would like to return`'b'`.

Comment: your dictionary is actually {'ac': 200, 'ab': 100, 'ad': 500}

Comment: i'd say he is looking for the closest element to a

Comment: I think what the first two comments are getting at is that the asker has used the syntax `'a''b''` rather than the equivalent `'ab'` which suggests confusion over the syntax of the language.

Comment: Before the edit, dictionary keys were 2-character strings, now they are length-2 tuples. Not really the same, but kind of similar indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min(((d[s],s) for s in d if s.startswith('a')))[1][1:]
```

The `min` finds the minimum *value* in the `(value, key)` pairs, and then we take the key (with the smallest value), and display the latter part of it. This uses the fact that `min`, minimises over the *first* value in a tuple.

And we could generalise to find the minimum which "starts with a string" `a` as:

```
def smallest_value_of_key_startswith(a, d):
    min(((d[s],s) for s in d if s.startswith(a)))[1][len(a):]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def f(d, key):        
    return min(((v, k[1]) for k, v in d.items() if k[0] == key))[1]

distance = {('a','b'):100,('a','c'):200,('a','d'):500}    
print f(distance, 'a')
>>> 'b'

distance = {('c','e'):200,('d','c'):100,('c','d'):500}    
print f(distance, 'c')
>>> 'e'
```