# Python dictionaries - find second key in tuple which yields minimum value

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python dictionaries - find second character in a 2-character string which yields minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284913/python-dictionaries-find-second-character-in-a-2-character-string-which-yields)

I would like to submit the first item of a tuple key and return the remaining item of that key which minimizes the tuple key value.

For example:

```
d = {('a','b'): 100,
     ('a','c'): 200,
     ('a','d'): 500}
```

If I were to pass in `'a'`, I would like to return `'b'`.

Comment: You have an entirely wrong data structure to do this efficiently, brute force will have to do.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I agree, the most efficient way would be `d = {'a':{100:'b',200:'c',500:'d'}}` that could be retrieved using `get_min = lambda d,k: d[k][min(d[k])]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is unnecessary here:

```
>>> d ={('a','b'):100,('a','c'):200,('a','d'):500,('b','c'):1000,('b','e'):100}
>>> def func(d, k0):
...     return min((k for k in d if k[0] == k0), key=d.get)[1]
... 
>>> func(d, 'a')
'b'
>>> func(d, 'b')
'e'
```

This works by using a generator expression to give only the keys in the dictionary whose first element matches the input, and uses as the associated "weight" (unfortunately named the "key" here in this context) the associated value in the dictionary.  Dictionaries have a `.get` method which returns the value given a specific key, so that's the natural one to use.

Note that in the case of ties, this returns an arbitrary key.

Comment: just curious in terms of time is list comprehension about equal to filter?

Comment: There's no listcomp here, only a genexp.  As for performance, you'd have to run `timeit` to see: I always guess wrong (`filter` would be fast, you'd think, but `lambda`s tend to be slower than C-level methods, so who knows?)

Answer (score 2):

```
def func(d,y):
    lis=sorted((x for x in d.items() if x[0][0]==y),key=lambda x:x[1])
    return lis[0][0][1]


d ={('a','b'):100,('a','c'):200,('a','d'):500,('b','c'):1000,('b','e'):100}
```

output:

```
>>> func(d,'a')
'b'
>>> func(d,'b')
'e'
```

Comment: imho this is more clear than my answer in what its doing +1

Answer (score 0):

```
  def minval(my_dict,var_name):
      return min(filter(lambda x: x[0][0] == var_name,my_dict.items()),key=lambda x:x[1])[0][1]

  print      minval(d,'a')
```

I think Ashwins answer is probably better by pythonic simple is better than complex standards and they probably perform simillarly on a time scale ... his may even be faster ...